# [08006][17002] IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter in use is Invalid

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datagrip

I'm trying to connect local oracle database with Datagrip. But when I click the "test connection" I got this error.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using CLRExrProc? That isn't intended for general use. What is your actual database SID; or preferably, use a service name; `lsnrctl services` will show you what is available.

Comment: I deleted the oracle and installed again but now it says :
The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [72000][1017] ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied